# Flutter TextFormField iOS keyboard white on suggestion

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I have a `TextFormField` and when I type something, as soon as the iOS keyboard has a suggestion, the text is not visible.
My app has dark mode only and the text color is white. As soon as the suggestion appears there is just a white block.
This does not happen on Android and this does also not happen on iOS with the GBoard google keyboard app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
TextFormField(
  // ...
  style: TextStyle(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```

**Edit**
Also edit your `ThemeData` and change the `textSelectionColor` property value as following

```
ThemeData(
  // ...
  textSelectionColor: Colors.transparent, // or your desired color
),
```

Comment: This does not work for me. But when I type in a text without getting any suggestion and then select the complete text, there is the same white box. How can I change the selected text color?

Comment: The `textSelectionColor` solved it, thanks!